# How to get TypeScript, StandardJS and the js.map file all working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, standardjs

So we're using TypeScript.
We need to have the final JavaScript conforming to standardJS https://standardjs.com/
So I was looking at running "standard --fix" to make the .js files generated from the .ts files all fixed and confirming to the standard.
But this seems to stop debugging being able to work, no breakpoints are mapping correctly.
I'm assuming this is due to the .js.map file not correctly matching the rows in the .js file.
It does seem to work OK for smaller .ts files even if the line numbers but not the larger .ts files.

NOTES: When I set a breakpoint in a .ts file after running "standard --fix" then it looks disabled and says "Unbound breakpoint" when you hover over it. When I set a breakpoint on the generated .js file that all works fine.

Any help/info/ideas gratefully received.

Comment: https://standardjs.com/#can-i-use-a-javascript-language-variant-like-flow-or-typescript

Comment: A workaround could be to apply `standard --fix` only when building for production, and not while you are debugging.

Comment: Or should we be using babel ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/babel-with-typescript.html

Comment: https://standardjs.com/#can-i-use-a-javascript-language-variant-like-flow-or-typescript just changes the .ts to have the standard doesn't help sort out the .js file generated from .ts or the mapping